# How to change the screen resolution of the virtual console on an external VGA?

Tags: 12.04, lubuntu, xrandr, virtual-console, randr

I've found helpful solutions to `randr` problems on the regular GUI (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>) but this question is about resizing the virtual console, which doesn't have good google results.

I've been using `arandr` to change VGA outputs between my 1680×1050 monitor and digital projector with I think a different ratio (definitely smaller numbers). Noticed a few quirky things like I need to resize `VGA`, then resize `LVDS`, then resize `VGA` again (possibly multiple repeats) to reduce the maximum screen size

Between going back and forth these two devices the most recent time I somehow reduced the resolution of the virtual console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>) which I use most of the day.

The virtual console still shows up correctly on the `LVDS` but I'd like to change the `VGA` resolution so I can watch the virtual console on my monitor. It was projecting at a nice large resolution before my most recent switch to projector and back. (I even looked at the virtual console on the projector and it was large resolution.)

Any suggestions what I might need to do here? I tried `xrandr --output VGA --mode 1680x1050` and got `can't open display` error.

Let me know if there's any other info I should give.

Comment: ok, just figured out something which I guess should have been obvious. `xrandr` obviously can't run in the virtual console because there's no `X` there. Still don't know what to run though.

Comment: From some more googling it looks like there are various VGA options in the `grub` bootloader. But I've changed this virtual console resolution before (accidentally) without rebooting.

Comment: `resizecons` doesn't currently ship with Ubuntu (it's marked as a bug) and `stty size` is not the command to use either.

Comment: [same problem](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2001903) two months ago. Perhaps this is a new `12.04` issue.

Comment: Aaaaand the problem seems to have somehow "fixed itself". Don't know what I did.

Answer (score 1):

In Grub2, as a Linux kernel boot parameter, this is what I add to the boot line on my servers...

```
# It follows the format of video=conn:res[M][R][-bpp][@refresh][i][m][eDd] 
# Example:
nomodeset video=VGA:1024x768@60m
```

What this says is to turn kms modesetting off... Manually set the framebuffer for port VGA to 1024x768 @60Hz with a margin. Search on the "format" above and it will explain all the options for that, as well as all the valid conn names.

Comment: Thanks. I can't test this but appreciate your answering.